# Why is the euphemism "comfort women" so heavily used?

Tags: euphemisms

Most reporting on women used for sex by the Japanese armed forces during WWII use the euphemism "comfort women", derived from the Japanese word "ianfu", which means "comfort women". Sometimes the euphemism is put in scare quotes, and sometimes the term is defined, but it's used nonetheless.

Why is the euphemism used so heavily?

One potential explanation is that media has bias and want to soften Japan's past misdeeds, but most of the reporting I've seen it in takes it for granted that the action of using women this way was wrong.

Is it because there's no alternative which is as concise and specific to this action?

Comment: You may not realise it, but part of the reason for the scare quotes on "comfort women" is to convey *negative associations*. That's to say, referencing them that way doesn't "soften" anything - if anything, it's precisely the opposite.

Comment: What @FumbleFingers said. Use of the term is akin to talking about "Arbeit macht frei". It is hardly a euphemism in the current context, though it was no doubt a euphemism by the Japanese at the time. "Comfort women" was the term used, and it is still the term used. It was a euphemism, but it no longer is (IMO).

Comment: The only other term one might use would be something along the lines of "sex slaves", and that would be a bit too "rough" for many media, especially if children might read/hear it.  The meaning of "comfort ladies" is well-understood, so nothing's really being swept under the carpet.

Comment: The negativity that @FumbleFingers mentions arises partly from the fact that the program was so odioius that the Japanese authorities couldn't bring themselves to call what they were doing by its right name.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The scare quotes definitely convey negative connotations, but even with scare quotes, I definitely think "comfort women" is softer than "sex slaves", "forced prostitutes", or "rape victims" (let alone, say, "women who were systematically beaten and raped day and night for months on end by large numbers of foreign soldiers"). Do you really believe otherwise, or are you exaggerating for effect?

Comment: @ruakh: I really, *really, **really*** believe you are MISTAKEN!!! Scare quotes are a very distinctive orthographic device, akin to using italics, bold fonts, multiple exclamation marks, and capital letters. To some extent, when a "novel" usage is demarcated in this way, the implication is often that the writer simply can't think of (or bring himself to fully articulate) a more accurate way to express himself. Thus the reader is invited to *imagine* exactly what's being referenced, which in many cases will be *much worse* than your 20-word paraphrase (yet still fall short of the full horror).

Comment: @HotLicks Euphemisms never actually fool anyone, they just service a social function to avoid being blatant about things we find uncomfortable to discuss in public. For instance, if a woman says she's going to "powder her nose", everyone knows what she's really going to do.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I strongly believe that too much emphasis is often given to "scare quotes" (and I find the term itself somewhat objectionable).  The main reason for using quotes around a term such as "comfort women" is to indicate to the reader that the term has a specific meaning that is more than/different from the meaning of its component words.  Italics are often used for the same reason.  The use of this typographic convention, of itself, is not pejorative.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I'm not wild about the term "scare quotes" myself, but it's certainly better than "shudder quotes" or "sneer quotes". Having said that,  the latter clearly alludes to the fact that they're often used to pour scorn on a term (and in this specific case, not only to ridicule a totally inappropriate euphemistic usage, but to express antipathy to the underlying referent). I really don't think the "primary purpose" here is to indicate that the term doesn't have its "primary meaning" (whatever that might be, since there isn't one). It's very specifically about negative associations.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - So you're saying that, when I discuss the nature of the variable named "quantity" in a post to StackOverflow, I'm casting aspersions on that variable?

Comment: @Hot Licks: Obviously it's unlikely you would have any such intention (and it's almost inconceivable any reader would understand it, even if that's what you actually *meant*). But quite apart from the fact that actual "scare quotes" can be used for different purposes, I don't think anyone could seriously argue that's an appropriate designation for the quote marks involved in a written "discussion" of a variable named ***"quantity"***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yet I have several times seen comments to the effect of "Why did you uses scare quotes around the variable name -- you should use `backquotes` or *italics*?"  And, ironically, they often put quotes around "scare quotes" when they say that.

Comment: @Hot Licks: In the "technical documentation" context it's a good idea to adopt a consistent typographic style - but if you move between companies you're very likely to find that they don't all endorse the *same* style. Your comments imply you think there is (or at least *should* be) a single universally-acknowledged set of rules governing such matters. But there isn't (and imho there never could be), so at the end of the day it's just a matter of either "Follow your own inclinations" (but at least be consistent) or "Choose your style guide" (or use the one you're *told* to use).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I was referring to comments on StackOverflow.  (In fact, I'm not sure I've ever seen the term "scare quotes" anywhere other that on StackExchange boards.)

Comment: @Hot Licks: I haven't seen much of [tchrist](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/2085/tchrist?tab=activity) yet this year, but he's definitely the one to consult of you want an authoritative summary of what typographic conventions [he thinks] we *should* be using, both here and on StackOverflow. Me, I just  make it up as I go along.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I personally just try to be consistent, and not vary too much from the norm.  But often some creativity is necessary when you're tossing around terms at several different levels.

Comment: As an example of quote use, I was just in a discussion about "pay phones" vs "pay stations" as the term for a public coin-operated phone.  Certainly quotes around those terms are merited, but there's nothing at all "scary" about them (unless you're frightened of hulking black boxes).  The term "scare quotes" is totally unjustified.

Comment: @Hot Licks: In BrE, ***payphone*** is a perfectly ordinary word, and has been for at least the past 50 years. But that sense of *"**pay station**"* would definitely need scare quotes and/or a definition immediately following first use in most contexts. To the extent that I recognise the term at all, I'd assume it just meant *any* place where you pay for something (particularly, using an unattended *machine*, such as an automated ticket dispenser at a railway station or car park).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Why does "pay station" not simply need "quotes".  Why do they have to be "scare quotes"??

Comment: @Hot Licks: Because scare quotes are the subset of quotes / quotation marks applicable to the specific context here. As I said, I'm not too keen on the name - but it's a well-known usage that *exactly* references what we're talking about. In practice I usually would just call them quote marks, since the context would normally indicate whether I was talking about marks indicating direct speech / quotations. Similar to my occasional use of "table salt" to specifically reference sodium chloride (since technically, things like potassium chloride / copper sulphate are also "salts").

Answer (score 44, accepted):

According to Kirsten Orreill, ['Who are the Ianfu (Comfort Women)?'](http://newvoices.jpf-sydney.org/2/chapter7.pdf), in *New Voices in Japanese Studies*, 2, the term is a calque, a literal translation of the Japanese bureaucratic term:

> The term itself is translated from the Japanese abbreviation Ianfu, hereafter referred to in this paper. As the Chinese characters 慰 安 [i : an ] (comfort or solace) and 婦 [fu] (woman or wife) suggest, the women’s literal purpose was to offer solace and comfort to Japan’s Imperial Forces. However, the initiation of the Ianfu system was primarily a contiguous response to the Nanking massacre where it became evident to the Japanese authorities that future measures needed to be taken to minimise rapes of local women by Japanese soldiers in war zones. Thus, in order to minimise these rapes,the Ianfu system was used to procure women for the sexual gratification of the Japanese soldiers.

It's used, then, because it was the official name of the program.  An analogy is the German euphemism *Endlösung*, 'final solution', the official term for the Nazi campaign of terror and genocide against the Jews, Romany, Communists and other undesirables. I don't think anybody is misled by either euphemism today (supposing anybody ever was). Indeed, their use tends to lend an extra chill to references: it reminds us of what Hannah Arendt called "the banality of evil".

Comment: I think it (and also "final solution" as you reference) also add specificity (anyone familiar with the term already knows which case precisely you are talking about). Further, the euphemism being so blatant using it brings condemnation of the euphemism itself and with it the sort of regime that would carry out atrocities under such euphemisms. If anything the terms have become dysphemism and express condemnation.

Comment: @Jon: Right on! I think you've hit the nail on the head by saying that terms like "comfort women" and "final solution" are effectively ***dysphemisms*** (personally, I doubt that they were *ever* "euphemisms" when translated into English).

Comment: @FumbleFingers we have English-originated terms that were euphemisms (or at least jargon with euphemism as part of their mechanism, if not all) that are similarly used as dysphemisms. Some even simultaneously still being used euphemistically by some while their opponents use them dysphemistically: "Collateral damage" for example.

Answer (score 10):

As suggested in the comment, there are alternatives such as *sex slaves*, *forced prostitutes* or *enforced prostitutes*, etc. There has been much debate about whether to call them *comfort women* is appropriate and right because it doesn't have any connotation of *forceful and cruel characteristics* of the sex slavery.

In the linked Wikipedia article about [Comfort women](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comfort_women) they were:

> women and girls who were forced into sexual slavery by the Imperial
>   Japanese Army in occupied territories before and during World War II.

The word **慰安 (comfort)** was also used to describe Japanese [**prostitute stations**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_slavery) set up for occupying Allied troops immediately following Word War II.

> The **Recreation** and **Amusement** Association (特殊慰安施設協会 Tokushu Ian
>   Shisetsu Kyōkai (Special Comfort Facility Association)?) (RAA) was the
>   largest of the organizations established by the Japanese government to
>   provide organized prostitution and other leisure facilities for
>   occupying Allied troops immediately following World War II.
>
> The RAA established its first brothel on 28 August: the Komachien in Ōmori. By December 1945, the RAA owned 34 facilities, 16 of which were **"comfort stations"**. The total number of prostitutes employed by the RAA amounted to 55,000 at its peak.

You could notice how inappropriate (or weird) the Recreation and Amusement Association sounds.

The same Chinese characters 慰安 [i : an ] (comfort or solace) were translated into *Recreation and Amusement* in the name RAA. The name 特殊慰安施設協会 should be translated word-for-word into Special (特殊), Comfort or Comfort Station (慰安), Facility or Establishment (施設), Association (協会).

It would be far mare inappropriate to call them *Recreation Women* or *Amusement Women*. *Comfort women* became  an [**appellative**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/appellative) or **quasi-proper noun** to describe those women forced to work as sex slaves in Asia during World War II.

The [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comfort+woman%2C+comfort+women&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=6&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomfort%20woman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomfort%20women%3B%2Cc0) for *comfort woman* and *comfort women* shows that both terms are (relatively) new from around 1990s and this [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sex+slaves%2C+sex+slave&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=6&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csex%20slaves%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csex%20slave%3B%2Cc0) shows that the word *sex slave* and *sex slaves* are also relatively new.

Comment: I think "Special Comfort Facility Association" is Wikipedia providing a literal translation of a Japanese term, rather than indicating "comfort" was used in that context at that time.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Facility might be the better choice (I edited the answer) than establishment in word-for-word translation. Anyway, I wanted to emphasize the fact that the Chinese character 慰安 was not only translated to *comfort*.

Comment: I'm referring to the sentence "The word comfort was also used to describe Japanese prostitute stations set up for occupying Allied troops immediately following Word War II.". I don't doubt that terms in Japanese were used post-war that, if translated to English, could potentially contain the word "comfort", but I'm doubtful as to whether the word "comfort" was used in English at that time to describe post-WWII facilities.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Based on your comment, I edited to replace *comfort* with *慰安 (comfort)* and included two Ngram Viewers. Sex slave and sex slaves seem to be also relatively new.

Answer (score 5):

Japanese government and Korean government recently reached an agreement on the settlement of a long-lasting issue of Comfort Women, which has been a persistent stinging thorn to our heart.

“Comfort Women” is a direct and literal translation of Japanese words, 慰安婦. But many people forget that it is always preceded with the word, 従軍 meaning ‘in, or serving for military service.” The “formal” description of “comfort women” is 従軍慰安婦, and its verbatim translation is “comfort women serving for the armed-forces.

The original intention of military-ruled Japanese government before and during WW II was, as I understand, (1) to provide solutions to soldier’s instinctive sexual desire, and (2) to protect soldier’s doing barbarous acts such as raping of local women by venting their sexual instinct through “Comfort-Women-in-military-service system.”

It is well-known fact that Japanese authority offered to set up R&R (Rest and Recreation) Center for Allied Occupation army to then GHQ in fear of massive outbreak of violent activities caused by oppressed sexual instinct among stationed occupation forces, and put into practice immediate after the WW II.
Please note that I have no intention to argue wrongness or righteousness of such practice here in this site.

Now, why is the euphemism used so heavily? It’s not euphemism. It’s a part of 従軍慰安婦 which was used publicly – I’m not saying officially – in Japan during the war time.

Comment: Seriously, it's not a euphemism just because it's in a different language? Are there no euphemisms in your language? What do you call soldiers who kidnap and repeatedly rape innocent women? If you call them "soldiers with instinctive sexual desire", that's euphemism, I think. If you call them "rapists who happen to be soldiers", or "soldier-rapists", or just "rapists", that's not euphemism. You use euphemism in your very answer. It may be ingrained, but it doesn't make it less of a euphemism. (I would be no less direct with euphemism in any other language.)

Comment: Please don't get me wrong, the service industry can include prostitutes, and if there were a group of such women following the military, comfort women could well be their name. But the "comfort women" were not voluntarily selling their services. They were forced into sexual servitude after being either abducted or lured with false promises of employment. Columbia University offers a course on "Comfort Women" in it's Asia studies, and even they say it is a Japanese euphemism.

Comment: "The so‐called “comfort women” (the term is a translation of a Japanese/Korean euphemism) were sexual slaves..." Why would they - a prestigious University - say this if it was untrue?

Comment: @Medica. I said I don’t want to get involved with the argument of “Comfort women” issue except linguistic aspect. I didn’t invent this word, nor was involved with enforcement of this system personally as well as you were not involved with the dropping A-bombs on Hiroshima and Nagasaki civilians. Let’s stop arguing its moralistic contexture. About the issue of whether “Comfort women” is a euphemism or not, it is a fact that there were many or some Japanese women who volunteered to do that business for the sake of much higher remuneration than millions of women laborers of sweat shops

Comment: Cont'd: in textile business who were called 女工 and women coal miners then quite common. I assume Military Force authority adopted the name of “従軍慰安婦 – Comfort women for military service” rather than calling “従軍娼婦 – Prostitute for military service,” which sounds less denigrating in recruiting “candidates.” This is very delicate issue, and you can argue hundreds hours. I don’t want to go any further on this issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34227/discussion-between-yoichi-oishi-and-medica). No thanks.I think I've finished my point. I'm off the table.

Comment: At the back of my mind, I was wondering whether "comfort women" is a euphemism. I'm not sure whether I agree with this logic, but it's given me pause for thought.